# javascript run a bunch of functions

Tags: javascript

How do i execute a bunch of functions without knowing their names?

```
var theseFn = function () {
  func1 : function () {},
  func2 : function () {}
}
```

I want to run everything in theseFn. How do I do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will execute all functions on an object, assuming no arguments:

```
for (var i in theseFn) if (typeof(theseFn[i]) === "function") theseFn[i]();
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use a for-in loop (with a `hasOwnProperty` check, of course) with bracket notation for object property access:

```
for(var functionName in theseFn) {
    if(theseFn.hasOwnProperty(functionName)&&typeof theseFn[functionName]=="function") {
        theseFn[functionName]();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the properties of `theseFn`, invoking every one in turn:

```
for (func in theseFn)
{
    theseFn[func]();
}
```

Comment: @icktoofay: That's what happens when you 're in a hurry. Fixed, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean

```
var theseFn = {
   func1 : function () {},
   func2 : function () {}
}
```

then you can say

```
 theseFn.func1();
```